# Omitting "have" in Perfect aspect

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

I often see phrases like:

- I just seen her.
- He just found out.

Are they correct in terms of grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is non-standard.  This appears to be a non-standard present perfect with "have" reduced to nothing

> I have just seen her -> I've just seen her -> I just seen her.

The second may be interpreted as the  simple past (the past tense of "find" is "found"), which is standard grammar. However most British speakers would use present perfect in this context. So it might be understood to be a non-standard construction of the present perfect.  Since the meaning is almost identical, it is hard to unpick what is the actual intention of the speaker.

Comment: It is possible contrive a context where the simple past is natural for the second sentence. Q: "How did Bob find out my secret? Did you tell him?" A: "I don't know. He just found out."

Answer (score 1):

"I just seen her" is certainly not grammatical in Standard English. It is found in non-standard, relaxed speech, where function words are usually omitted for convenience.

"He just found out" is ambiguous: it could be the basic past tense construction or a non-standard variant of "he has just found out". I believe that the latter case is less likely.